# How to create a new reusable custom validator

Tags: javascript, express-validator

Is there a way to create a validator method to reuse in different places?

Currently, I have a custom validator with some logic, but I'm repeating that logic on other validators and I was wondering if there's a way to create a custom method to avoid repeating code like that.

This is what I have in some validators:

```
const exampleValidator = [
    body().custom((value) => {
        allowed = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3', ...];
        /**
           bunch of logic to allow certain fields...
        */
        
    }),
    body('parameter', 'invalid parameter provided').isEmpty()
];
```

> Note: This custom validator is built to only allow certain fields sent in the request. Given an array, the custom validator checks if the sent
> request only contains the allowed fields.

**What I want:** I was wondering if there's a way we can create a custom validator to get something like this:

```
const exampleValidator = [
    body().allowCertainFields(['field1', 'field2']),
    body('parameter', 'invalid parameter provided').isEmpty()
];
```

If there's a way, I don't know where I could create this `allowCertainFields()` custom method **without modifying any core file of express-validator**.

Because another way to do that is doing something like this:

```
const exampleValidator = [
    body().custom((value) => {
        allowed = ['param1', 'param2'];
        return allowCertainFields(value, allowed);
        
    }),
    body('parameter', 'invalid parameter provided').isEmpty()
];
```

But first I wanted to know if what I want to do is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may create validator function anywhere, even in other module and import them into place, and pass them as argument into `body().custom()`.

Something like:

```js
const create = (allowed) => {
  return (value) => {
    /**
       bunch of logic to allow certain fields...
    */
    return true;
  }
}
const allowCertainFields = create(['field1', 'field2']);

const exampleValidator = [
  body().custom(allowCertainFields),
  body('parameter', 'invalid parameter provided').isEmpty()
];
```